# How to discard XML attributes when running XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XSLT that works perfectly to generate new XML from an existing XML data flow. BUT, the root element lists several attributes that when present cause the XSLT to fail to parse the data.

What change to the XSLT do I need to make to make it ignore the attributes?

Here is the root element:

```
   <CrystalReport xmlns="urn:crystal-reports:schemas:report-detail"  
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:crystal-reports:schemas:report-detail 
      http://www.businessobjects.com/products/xml/CR2008Schema.xsd">
```

If I simply delete the attributes the XSLT runs fine. If they are present it ignores the entire file.

Do you need to see my XSLT to help?

Here is the XSLT. (Can I modify the XSLT to simply ignore the namespace?):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!-- DWXMLSource="STX050 Course Descriptions Parsed.xml" -->
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>

<xsl:key name="courses-by-title" match="Details" use="Section/DEPTSDESC1" />

<xsl:template match="CrystalReport">

<crystalreports>
<xsl:for-each select="Details[count(. | key('courses-by-title', Section/DEPTSDESC1)[1]) = 1]">
<xsl:sort select="Section/DEPTSDESC1" />
<department>
<Sectiontitle><xsl:value-of select="Section/DEPTSDESC1"/></Sectiontitle><xsl:text>
</xsl:text>

<xsl:for-each select="key('courses-by-title', Section/DEPTSDESC1)">
<xsl:sort select="Section/DEPTSDESC1" />
<Details> 
<course><xsl:value-of select="Section/DEPTSDESC1"/></course><xsl:text> </xsl:text><courseno><xsl:value-of select="Section/CRSNO1"/></courseno><xsl:text>
</xsl:text><class><xsl:value-of select="Section/CRSTITLE1"/></class><xsl:text>
</xsl:text><classcredit><xsl:value-of select="Section/CRSMINCRED1"/></classcredit><xsl:text> credit hours
</xsl:text><description><xsl:value-of select="Section/CRSDESC1"/></description> 
</Details><xsl:text>
</xsl:text>

</xsl:for-each>
</department>
</xsl:for-each>
</crystalreports>

</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yes, it would be helpful to see at least some of your XSLT.

Comment: Your XSLT is not handling the namespaces correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an attribute:

```
xmlns="urn:crystal-reports:schemas:report-detail"
```

It is a namespace declaration.  It appears that your XML inputs are in this namespace, and the XSLT is not finding anything from your document most likely because all of your XPaths are in the null namespace.  What you need to do is declare this namespace in your XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
   xmlns:cr="urn:crystal-reports:schemas:report-detail">
```

Note that I've assigned it the prefix `cr`.  It's necessary to give the namespace some prefix in this case.

Then you need to use that same prefix in your XPaths:

```
<xsl:template match="cr:CrystalReports">

...

<xsl:value-of select="cr:SomeNode/cr:AnotherNode" />
```

and so on.

One gotcha here is that if the **attributes** in your XML have no prefix in the source document, then they *are* in the null namespace and you should **not** use a prefix when referring to them.  For example:

If you had an element like this in that same XML document:

```
<ReportItem id="5" />
```

you would refer to that attribute as `@id`, not `@cr:id`:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="cr:ReportItem[@id = 5]" />
```

Comment: +1: 'Yes, it would be helpful to see at least some of your XSLT' - but you did not even needed it..

Comment: It's such a common question/mistake that when people say "my XSLT doesn't work" you can confidently tell them "check your namespaces".

Comment: The namespace is generated by the database function. I have no control over their namespace. If I delete this whole declaration the XSLT functions perfectly. Is there a reason to change the stylesheet? What am I losing by totally ignoring the namespace declaration?

Comment: What do you mean when you say you have no control over their namespace?  Won't their use of namespaces be consistent? I'm not sure that you'd actually be _losing_ anything, except that you'd be performing an extra processing step just to circumvent the "correct" way to handle the XML. And if for some reason there were a software update or you started getting your CrystalReports from another system and the XML started to use namespace prefixes but continue to use the same namespaces (which would still conceptually be the exact same format), then your XSLT would stop working again.

Comment: It may be consistent, I'm not sure. I just got involved recently. The client is a using a function that, they say, they have little or no control over. So, I am just wondering what value this namespace has if it is badly created according to the comments above? I am just trying to produce a printed catalog from this XML. We are just working with what we have and trying to get the job done.

Comment: Well, firstly, I think you need to find out what your client means when they say they have little or control over the XML. Does that mean they do not have the liberty to decide what its format is, or does that mean that it changes erratically without warning?  If it's the first one, then a properly written XSLT should have no problem.  If it's the second one, then you have a problem no matter how you look at it.

Comment: When I mentioned the concept of namespaces switching prefixes above, I was just speaking hypothetically, but my point was that if your XSLT is written properly _it doesn't matter_ if the prefixes change, and having the prefixes change does not constitue the XML being badly created. Varying prefixes will only be a problem if you try to use hacks to circumvent the namespaces.